# R studio failing to use rJava lib and failing javareconf

Tags: r, rjava

I'm running Rstudio on its own server.
Java is installed with good java_home and bin.
R is installed. rJava is installed.

Tried to do command: `library("rJava")` but had issues with `libjvm.so`, do following Rstudio recommandation I did `sudo R CMD javareconf` with root.

Here is the output of my javareconf:

```
Java interpreter : /home/scoremd/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/bin/java
Java version : 1.7.0_03
Java home path : /home/scoremd/jdk1.7.0_03
Java compiler : /home/scoremd/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /home/scoremd/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /home/scoremd/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/jar
NOTE: Your JVM has a bogus java.library.path system property!

Trying a heuristic via sun.boot.library.path to find jvm library...
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64:$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64 -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
JNI cpp flags : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
```

Seems there is issue with finding the java library path... but my java is working fine and R also.

I didn't receive any solution from RStudio support and community (told me to ask in SO ....).

Comment: The `javareconf` output above is just fine (it is just telling you that it was working around bugs in your Java) - it found all the paths as you can see. Did you re-install rJava from sources *after* running `javareconf`? Also note that for this to work whatever you're running (Rstudio?) must be started with the `R` script (i.e. if your line doesn't start with `R ...` it's unlikely to work). If you still have issues, provide details (what exactly are you running and what errors you get). BTW: support for rJava is on the stats-rosuda-devel mailing list.

Comment: I have the same problem! How did you solve this?

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/15806471/2161065 ?

best regards, Sascha

Comment: Have you tried installing the rJava package as a root user?

Answer (score 2):

I have rstudio-server installed on my Centos server. There are a couple of users using rstudio and we decided to upgrade R from 3.6 to 4.0.

After the upgrade :

- all users were running R 4.0.
- No user could install rJava using install.package('rJava'). This error always popped up

> configure: error: Cannot compile a simple JNI program. See config.log for details.
> Make sure you have Java Development Kit installed and correctly registered in R.
> If in doubt, re-run "R CMD javareconf" as root.
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’

- Running **SUDO R CMD javareconf** went smoothly, and also when I opened R as root and went along  and tried **install.packages('rJava')** it installed the package just fine. (unbeknownst to me, root ran R 3.6 and users 4.0, see solution below)
- However it did not work installing the package for users in R studio server. Always stating the same "try running sudo R CMD javareconf" as if the Java path for the users was wrong.
- so we tried setting the "JAVA_HOME" variable to the same path that java jdk was installed in (found by searching installed packages in yum). That did not solve it.

**my solution**
I saw that root was running version 3.6 of R while all users ran 4.0. This was because I had installed 4.0 in another directory.. The directory of R 4.0 happens to be found first by the users. However for the root user... it finds the path of R 3.6 first.
So I set the path to the 4.0 folder in the $PATH variable of the root user, so that would find version 4.0 before finding R 3.6

- echo $PATH
- export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
- echo $PATH

Then I ran R as that user and ran "R CMD javareconf", installed the packages and all users are happy and working again.

(disclaimer, I'm not a experienced linux admin, there may be a better solution for running different R versions)

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time since I used `rJava`, and it was on Windows, but I have some notes which may help you:

- **Make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path**

  - (also confirmed using `Process Explorer` that `jri.dll` is being loaded)
- The R process loads up `jvm.dll` when you do `library(rJava)`

Replace `jvm.dll` iny my notes above with `libjvm.so` in your case, and `jri.dll` with whatever .so file is relevant to you.